# GRUB partition error

Tags: ubuntu, partition, grub, reboot

This is the first time this has happened to me. I don't use Linux on a regular basis, except for some project work.

I had logged in today, finished my work and restarted it so I could go into Windows (I have both Windows and Linux in my computer).

But when I rebooted it gave me this error:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of partition.  
grub rescue>
```

I have not tweaked with the software. As I said I don't use it so frequently.
Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you changed you partition table or installed another hard drive? More info please.

Comment: No I didn't do any of those. All I did was log in , go to firefox and into my college website , did some work and got out to reboot and get into windows.This error happened when I rebooted.

Comment: Perhaps you could google this error, first link goes to this howto http://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error

Answer (score 0):

Grub2 has two parts -- one in the MBR and the other one on a regular partition.
The rescue prompt means grub has failed to load its second part.
To fix that, you need to reinstall grub from a real system. Either you can boot from live CD/USB (easy), or you can redirect the rescue terminal to load the other parts, if you know where from (not so easy).

Check out:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

Comment: ok,this is what I did.I made my usb bootable, and loaded the latest ubuntu version(14.04),but I think the current ubuntu version on my computer is 13 point something.I continued. I booted using the usb stick and, don't know if this is right, got the install ubuntu 14.04.2 screen , instead of rectifying the grub rescue problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Boot with Ubuntu Live CD or USB.
2.Find your ubuntu partition:
`sudo blkid`
Mine show `/dev/sda1`

```
[~] : sudo blkid                                                                                                                                                18:05:04
/dev/sda1: UUID="122d2898-41c4-4d0b-a6e3-efdabacc0910" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b342201c-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="ssd2" UUID="10A1139E10A1139E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b342201c-02"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="64Win7" UUID="01D25439F551BF10" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f0b1ebb0-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="RELAX" UUID="9626FEB726FE9787" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f0b1ebb0-02"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="CLGT" UUID="E4481765481735B0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="c887c887-01"
/dev/loop0: UUID="c901eeeb-0431-40dd-bac7-6ced930103b1" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/docker-8:1-1327350-pool: UUID="c901eeeb-0431-40dd-bac7-6ced930103b1" TYPE="xfs"
```

3.Then rebuild your grub config:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
```

4.Reboot and you can use Ubuntu as normally.

Answer (score 0):

There is great GUI based utility Boot-Repair. Give it a try.

1.Boot with Ubuntu Live USB/DVD

2.Install Boot-Repair tool using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

For more information https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair